# Thought web services are supposed to be simple. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, visual-studio-2010, navision

First post on this wonderful site so feedback is greatly appreciated.

I followed a video instruction on Youtube by one of the NAV guru about consuming web services using C#.  I was able to replicate what he did in Sandbox, but now that I want to implement in Live it's a hit or miss type of ordeal.  If I made a small change somewhere the WS stopped working then after tweaking it here and there all of a sudden it works, then the cycle continues.

I basically created a form with two datagrids, one for sales header and one for sales line, with 3 buttons for New Order, New Line, and Save.  Below is my code. Can you point me in the right direction as to:
1. Why my code is not working?
2. Why it works and then stops working? What to watch out for?
3. In my original code, using System.Data is not showing an error.  I had to comment it out on this form because it has the scribbly line underneath.  How come?

I am a noob to web services and C# in general.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
//using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SalesOrderXML.ServiceReference3;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Net;

namespace SalesOrderXML
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Sales saleslive = new Sales();
        private SalesOrderService_PortClient svc1;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //BasicHttpBinding SalesOrderService_Binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            //SalesOrderService_Binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            //SalesOrderService_Binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

            var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

            svc1 = new SalesOrderService_PortClient(
                    //SalesOrderService_Binding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Cronus%20-%20LIVE%20COMPANY/Codeunit/SalesOrderService"));
                    binding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Cronus%20-%20LIVE%20COMPANY/Codeunit/SalesOrderService"));
            svc1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("testuser", "password123", "localhost");
            svc1.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation; 
            //SalesOrderService_Binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 99999999;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 99999999;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = 99999999;
            saleslive = new Sales();
            LoadData();
        }

        private void dataGridView3_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var orderlive = saleslive.Order[e.RowIndex];
            dataGridView4.DataSource = orderlive.Line;
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            svc1.ReadSalesOrders(ref saleslive);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = saleslive.Order;
        }

        private void SaveData()
        {
            svc1.SaveSalesOrders(saleslive);
            //dataGridview3.DataSource = saleslive.Order;

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            svc1.SaveSalesOrders(saleslive);  
            LoadData();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var orderlive = saleslive.Order;
            orderlive[orderlive.Count() - 1] = new Order { Line = new Line[] { } };
            Array.Resize(ref orderlive, saleslive.Order.Count() + 1);

            saleslive.Order = orderlive;
            dataGridView3.DataSource = saleslive.Order;   
        }

        private void dataGridView4_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var orderlive = saleslive.Order[dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Index];
            var line = orderlive.Line;
            if (line == null)
            {
                line = new Line[] { };
            }
            Array.Resize(ref line, line.Count() + 1);
            line[line.Count() - 1] = new Line
            {
                LineDocType = "Order",
                LineDocNo = "",
                LineNo = (line.Count() * 10000).ToString(),
                Type = "Item",
                SKU = "0316",
                Quantity = "10",
                Price = "1200",
                Amount = "12000",
                LineTotal = "12000"
            };
            orderlive.Line = line;
            dataGridView4.DataSource = line;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: define "stops working"? are any exceptions thrown? are any errors being logged? where does the application "stop working"?

Comment: "I had to comment it out on this form because it has the scribbly line underneath."

The System.Data Reference is missing from your Project. Assuming you're in Visual Studio, right-click on your project references, and add the reference to System.Data.

Comment: Does your app.config match on test and live?

Comment: Yes it does match (app.config).

Comment: stops working as in the form does come up in debug, but no data displayed like it did in sandbox

Comment: by the way, when I hit Start to debug, no error displayed at all, yet the form doesn't show any data.

Comment: The error I am getting now is about expecting element "order" from my current code unit/namespace but it's getting the wrong element from my test application instead, as if there's a crossover. My test was on a different port, different server. How can it see that even if I turned off all services on the test server???

Comment: Here is the exact error. Can anyone please tell me where to look to fix this??? Pretty pleaseeeee....  Imported XML cannot validate with the schema: The element 'Sales' in namespace 'urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50006' has invalid child element 'Order' in namespace 'urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50003'. List of possible elements expected: 'Order' in namespace 'urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50006'.